# How to determine number of children of a record?

Tags: nhibernate, count, nhibernate-criteria

Good afternoon everyone!

I'm studying NHibernate, and decided to make some changes. Among them, I noticed that some fields are unnecessary. So I bring my doubt:
I have a list, let's call it Class_List within each study class, I can have N students for each class. Within the list Class_List, I also have other properties as simple as the name of the class.
How I see it is unnecessary to store how many students I have in the database, I would, in a single query, how many records I have. This, using NHibernate.

Is this possible? How?

Best regards,

Gustavo.

Edit: I've forgot to say one thing... I want to return this number of record, as a column. But this column is not mapped in my .hbm.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

If students are mapped as a collection on Class, you can try using something like this:

```
var numberOfStudents = session.CreateCriteria<Class>()
    .Add(Restrictions.IdEq(1))
        .CreateCriteria("_students", "students")
        .SetProjection(Projections.RowCount())
        .UniqueResult<Int32>();
```

Where '1' is the id of the class (you can use other property) and '_students' is the name of the students collection.

Comment: I've forgot to say one thing... I want to return this number of record, as a column